# Git suddently reads public key instead of private one

Tags: git, github, ssh, gitlab

While everything worked fine the evening before, this morning I received the following error message when using `git push`:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/home/▉▉▉▉▉/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/home/▉▉▉▉▉/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub": bad permissions
```

The problem here is that git suddenly tries to load the public key instead of the private one.

I checked at `~/.ssh/` but no file has been modified for months. There were also modifications to the system settings for the last week and automatic updates are disabled.

The config file still reads:

```
Host github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

At this point I am puzzled on what could have gone wrong, any hint would be welcome :)

Thanks in advance

**[Edit] Solution:**

I did not find the root cause, but I realized that this problem did not affect git commands outside of the project directory. To solve it I simply cloned the repository again and replaced the .git folder with the one from the repo.

Comment: Are there any other IdentityFile directives in your .ssh config?

Comment: Git invokes an external `ssh` command to run things; this message comes from the external command, not from Git. If your ssh command was updated or you've started using an ssh agent, this affects how ssh itself works, and could explain the change.

Comment: @torek That is a good idea. I forgot about the ssh agent. After checking however, the ssh-agent was not modified either and killing it did not help